# trying a code to check expect statement in specman

Tags: specman

The following gives error for event a, b declaration as "unrecognized struct member". Please help me understand.

```
unit true_match_op {
  event a, b;

  my_task() @sys.any is {
  emit a;
  wait [2]*cycle;
  emit b;
  wait [5]*cycle;
  emit a;
  expect @b => {@a ; ~[..]};
};
run() is also {
start my_task();
stop_run();
};
};

extend sys {
  my_unit : true_match_op is instance;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to add a different `event` declaration for each event (this isn't C/C++). Also, an `expect` is a declarative construct. You have to declare it outside of the method:

```
unit true_match_op {
  event a;
  event b;

  my_task() @sys.any is {
  emit a;
  wait [2]*cycle;
  emit b;
  wait [5]*cycle;
  emit a;
  };

  expect @b => {@a ; ~[..]};
};
```